# Why is SQLite not found when I've added it to my Project's References?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8.1, nuget-package

I added "SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) to my project (Identity == SQLite.WinRT81, 
Version=3.8.6), and I do see it there beneath the project's References in the Solution Explorer. But this code:

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
```

...gives me "*The type or namespace name 'SQLite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

Right-clicking "SQLite" does not afford me a "Resolve" context menu option.

What do I need to do/add?

Comment: Can you resolve SQLiteConnection without adding the SQLite namespace in front? can you view the referenced library in ObjectBrowser?

Comment: Have you checked that you had added reference for that.

Comment: The reference is there alright.

Comment: @sa_ddam213: No to the first question, Yes to the second/last question.